# how to authenticate user in spring security with password encryption

Tags: spring-mvc, encryption, spring-security

i m using spring security in my application.in my database .the password is in encrypted form.so in login when i m sending the password,that password should be converted to the encrypted form then i should be able to compare the password which i m sending and the password which is present in the database.if it matches,successful login should occur.
this is my spring-security.xml

```
 <authentication-manager">
        <authentication-provider >
            <password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
                <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                    users-by-username-query="select email,password from user where email=?"
                     /> 
            </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
<beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>
```

and here is my user table which contains email,password,contactno,address.
any help how can i check the encrypted password value for the password which user entering and how to check whether it matechs or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own PasswordEncoder to transfer you user to spring secure.

```
@Component("PasswordEncoder")
public class PasswordEncoderimpl implements PasswordEncoder{
    @Override
    public String encodePassword(String rawPass, Object salt) {
        //it is the algorithm the transfer password to encrypted password
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isPasswordValid(String encPass, String rawPass, Object salt) {
        //encPass is the password in your database
        //rawPass is the password user entering 
        //then you can write it like
        return encPass.euqals(encodePassword(rawPass));
    }
}
```

Then your spring-security.xml will be:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>   
      <password-encoder ref="PasswordEncoder">
      </password-encoder>
     </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```